# SuperTable and related entries

Tags: relations, plugin-supertable

I'm trying to pull through content based on items within a SuperTable entries field.

After searching around I currently have this:

```
{% set individuals = craft.entries({section: 'barristers', relatedTo: { targetElement: entry, field: 'specialisms.linkToPage'}}) %}
{% for entry in individuals %}
  {{ entry.title }}
```

But it's not pulling anything through?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If `entry` is the entry with the Super Table field it is the `sourceElement` of that relation not the `targetElement`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use Craft's built in relations service for reverse relations lookup with Super Table. This is because there's actually a special case for nested relations, such as a Matrix field. Craft's own relations service has special handling for Matrix fields, which we also need to make use of.

Fortunately, Josh Angell (the star that he is) has submitted a fix for this, without having to hack the core. You'll just need to alter your code to use the following:

```
{% set reverseRelatedElements = craft.supertable.getRelatedElements({
  relatedTo: {
    targetElement: entry,
    field: 'specialisms.linkToPage'
  },
  section: 'barristers'
}) %}

{% for relatedEntry in reverseRelatedElements %}
  {{ relatedEntry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @crawf, do you know if there is a way to do a similar thing if the super table in question sits within a matrix block?

Comment: @MikeVaux did you ever work out if there is a way for ST in Matrix?

Comment: @JoshAngell No, afraid not. I didn't look into it in any great depth though.

Comment: I'm trying to also get this working for an ST in a Matrix. Did anyone get it going?

Comment: @richardpixel Any luck? I am stuck on this as well.

Comment: @DanielleLeComte Nope. I ended up swapping to Neo. Had similar issues but Benjamin sorted me out.