# How to query for multiple relations with SuperTable

Tags: relations, plugin-supertable

The relevant sections for this question are:

- Event: One relevant field. `guestAllocation` (SuperTable). Guest allocation is a table which selects a Partner (`Entries`) and how many people that partner is allowed to invite to an event
- GuestList - Two fields. `relatedEvent` (Entries) and `guestNames` (table)

Each Partner creates an Entry in the `guestList` channel. When they want to update the names of who they're inviting, they edit their post instead of creating a new one.

I'm trying to write a conditional which will let me check if there's already an entry in the `guestList` channel which is both related to that partner AND the event we're currently looking at. I need to check this as I have to update that Entry instead of creating a new one if it exists. The form is displayed on the Event page, so the `entry` variable is the current event we're dealing with.

I can't get my head round the `relations` documentation. How do I write this? The following is returning no results:

```
{% set partnerGuestList = craft.entries.section('guestList').relatedTo(
    { sourceElement: entry }, {# this event #}
    { targetElement: currentUser.partner.first() } {# current partner #}
) %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little hard to follow your example/description, but I'll take a stab at it.

The way I interpret your question, you need to pull a single `guestList` entry that is a) related to the current `event`, and b) shares a relationship with the `partner` entry set to the current user's `partner` field, via a `guestAllocation` SuperTable field owned by the `event` EntryModel (I'm assuming there's a `guestAllocation.partner` column, and that the event section has the `event` handle).

The first part is easy, although you seem to be confused about the `targetElement` and `sourceElement` parameters for the `relatedTo` method, so I'll try to clear that up:

Basically, in a `relatedTo` query you either specify the *target* element or the *source* element (never both) for the relationship – *depending on which element owns the field where relation is created*.

In your case, the `event` entry would be the **target** element, not the **source**, as the `relatedEvent` field (where the relation is created) belongs to the `guestList` entry model, not the `event`. In other words, the elements you *want* (the guest lists) should have the entry you *have* (the `event` entry) selected in a field (i.e. the `guestLists` entries "target" the `event` entry), not the other way around. If possible, you should also provide the field handle for the field where the relation is created, i.e. `relatedEvent` in your case. So, to pull *all* guestlists related to the current `event` entry, the correct `relatedTo` query would look like this:

```
{% set guestListsForEvent = craft.entries.section('guestList').relatedTo({
    targetElement: entry,
    field: 'relatedEvent'
}) %}
```

Obviously, you only want *one* guestlist – the one that is related to the current user's `partner` entry (phew!). Trouble is, that relationship doesn't really exist – it's actually more of a *condition*, where a) the `guestList` entry needs to be authored by a user with the correct `partner` relation, and b) the current `event` needs to have the correct `partner` entry (i.e. the current user's related `partner` entry) in its `guestAllocations` SuperTable field.

The second part is easy – you can set a `canCurrentUserCreateGuestList` flag inside a loop on the current `event` entry's `guestAllocations` field; if the correct `partner` event is found in the latter, the current user can create a new `guestList` entry and you should also query for an existing `guestList` entry:

```
{% set currentPartner = currentUser.partner.first %}
{% set currentUserCanCreateGuestList = false %}
{% for row in entry.guestAllocation %}
    {% if row.partner|length and row.partner.first.id == currentPartner.id %}
        {% set currentUserCanCreateGuestList = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Once you have that flag, you can use it in a conditional:

```
{% if currentUserCanCreateGuestList %}
   {# Query for existing guest list, create new list etc #}
{% endif %}
```

For the latter – the actual query to pull the `guestList` entry – a single `relatedTo` call obviously won't do the job here, but fortunately the workaround is quite simple – keeping in mind that you need to make sure that a) only 1 `guestList` entry is returned, and b) that entry is authored by a user with the same `partner` entry as the current user.

Again, the first part is easy – simply use `limit` and `first` to pull a single entry (I like to add a `|default(false)` filter to suppress errors if no entries are returned).

For the second part, you'll first need a list of user IDs for all the users that are related to the current user's `partner` entry, and then feed that array to the `authorId` parameter for the `craft.entries` call:

```
{# Get the IDs for all users related to the correct partner #}
{% set partnerUserIds = craft.users.relatedTo({
    targetElement: currentUser.partner.first,
    field: 'partner'
}).ids() %}

{# Get existing partner guest list related to the current event #}
{% set partnerGuestList = partnerUserIds|length ? craft.entries.section('guestList').relatedTo({
    targetElement: entry,
    field: 'relatedEvent'
}).authorId(partnerUserIds).limit(1).first|default(false) : false %}
```

The above code will return either a single `guestList` `EntryModel`, or `false`, if no related guestlist entries authored by a user with the correct `partner` entry exists. Whether or not the `event` entry has the current user's `partner` entry in one of its SuperTable `guestAllocation.partner` columns is irrelevant to the query itself, once you've established that the current `event` does indeed include the correct `partner` entry in its `guestAllocations` field (the conditional above).

Here's how the whole thing could look in context:

```
{# Can the current user create a guest list for this event? #}
{% set currentPartner = currentUser.partner.first %}
{% set currentUserCanCreateGuestList = false %}
{% for row in entry.guestAllocation %}
    {% if row.partner|length and row.partner.first.id == currentPartner.id %}
        {% set currentUserCanCreateGuestList = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# Get existing guest list #}
{% set partnerGuestList = false %}
{% if currentUserCanCreateGuestList %}
    {# Get the IDs for all users related to the correct partner #}
    {% set partnerUserIds = craft.users.relatedTo({
        targetElement: currentUser.partner.first,
        field: 'partner'
    }).ids() %}

    {# Get existing partner guest list related to the current event #}
    {% set partnerGuestList = partnerUserIds|length ? craft.entries.section('guestList').relatedTo({
        targetElement: entry,
        field: 'relatedEvent'
    }).authorId(partnerUserIds).limit(1).first|default(false) : false %}
{% endif %}

{# Create, edit, etc #}
{% if partnerGuestList %}
    {# Edit existing guest list #}
{% elseif currentUserCanCreateGuestList %}
    {# Create new guest list #}
{% else %}
    {# Do nothing? #}
{% endif %}
```

Note that the above isn't tested and there's a good chance I misinterpreted your question – but hopefully you'll take something away from it.

Finally, as your question also touches on the correct usage of `relatedTo` queries with multiple relation criteria: Your original syntax for the `relatedTo` call is close, but when you have multiple relation criteria, you'll need to include either `and` or `or` as the first parameter, specifying if *all* or *any* of the criteria should be met, respectively.

In your case, this means the *syntactically* correct multiple relation query for the partner guestlist should look something like this:

```
{% set partnerGuestList = craft.entries.section('guestList').relatedTo('and', 
    { target: entry, field: 'relatedEvent' },
    { targetElement: currentUser.partner.first(), field: 'guestAllocation.partner' }
) %}
```

Obviously, for reasons already explained the above query will return nothing. There's also the fact that SuperTable fields (in your case, the `guestAllocation.partner` field) doesn't actually work with the built-in relations functionality in Craft – meaning that *you can never use `craft.entries.relatedTo` when the relation is created in a SuperTable field*. Instead, SuperTable provides its own method for relation queries, which is explained in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/12123/1098). Again, I don't believe a single `relatedTo` call is the correct approach for your particular use case, but just wanted to mention it.

Just for funsies – here's how you could use SuperTable's `getRelatedElements` method to pull `event` entries based on `guestAllocation.partner` relations:

```
{% set partnerEvents = craft.supertable.getRelatedElements({
    relatedTo: {
        targetElement: currentUser.partner.first,
        field: 'guestAllocation.partner'
    },
    criteria: {
        section: 'event'
    }
}) %}
```

Comment: Just realized that if multiple Users can have the same 'partner' entry, the above falls apart. Let me know if thats the issue!

Comment: Nevermind, I updated the answer to accommodate that issue. It's even longer now! :D

Comment: Mats, thank you so much for taking the time to explain in so much detail and with examples! I really appreciate it. This has solved my question (there are more than one user per partner, so thanks for updating it again)