# Get data from another loop from outside the current loop

Tags: entries, frontend

Sorry the question title is so random - feel free to correct it to something more succinct if you can think of one.

Related question: [How to query for multiple relations with SuperTable](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13045/how-to-query-for-multiple-relations-with-supertable)

I have a front end Entry form which I'm using to create/edit an Entry which contains one field, a table called `guestNames`. The number of rows allowed in that table is set in another section's Entry (`event`). The SuperTable field in the `event` that defines how many rows are allowed is called `guestAllocation`. There two rows in that SuperTable, `partner` (Entries) and `places` (Number).

In my front end Entry form I want to create the correct number of input fields that are allowed. I have no problem doing that with this code:

```
{% for row in 1..entry.guestAllocation.relatedTo(partner).first.places %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fields[guestNames][{{ loop.index0 }}][col1]">Name {{ loop.index }}</label>
    <input id="fields[guestNames][{{ loop.index0 }}][col1]" type="text" name="fields[guestNames][{{ loop.index0 }}][col1]" class="form-control">
    {% if entry is defined %}{{ errorList(entry.getErrors('fields[guestNames]')) }}{% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

For the purposes of this example, that could be a static number like `5`. However, I also need to provide editing functionality rather than just creating a new entry each time, so with the following line:

`{% if partnerGuestList|length %}<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">{% endif %} {# If there's a guest list for this partner, update it #}`

I can check if the entry exists already. Now I need to provide the correct number of input fields from `entry.guestAllocation.relatedTo(partner).first.places`, but in those input boxes, I need to provide the data from the rows in the table `partnerGuestList` `guestNames`

To get the names I need, I can query:

```
{% for row in partnerGuestList.guestNames %}
    {{ row.guestName }}
{% endfor %}
```

Please comment if I can clarify any more!

**Short version:** How can I show data from an entry in a loop that isn't related to that entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting. I'm not able to test this right now, but I think this should work...

You could first loop through the results, adding them to an array as you go...

```
{% set guestNameValues = [] %}

{% for row in partnerGuestList.guestNames %}
    {% set guestNameValues = guestNameValues|merge([row.guestName]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

And then within your loop that displays the fields set the value as...

```
{{ guestNameValues[loop.index0] }}
```

That should get the corresponding name from the array you previously set.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, works perfectly. Thanks Andrew!